# Why does Strong's 1510 (εἰμί) have a different translation in the Bible like in John 10:30?

Tags: greek, john, translation-philosophy

[image: Greek interlinear for John 10:30]

What's your interpretation of εἰμί in John 10:30? He didn't use "are" but instead, He used the "I AM".

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember top take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  I am not sure what you are asking as "I am" does not occur in this text, nor anywhere else in John 10.

Comment: Strongs code does not represent the morphology of the word such as number, gender, case; for that you need to check morphological codes. Anyway, you need to avoid reading interlinear if you are not studying Greek. I recommend start with John Dobson's NT Greek book and duolingo. There is no such unique I AM in the NT or anywhere. It was a wild conjecture suggestion made by Chrysostom in 4th century to compare Jesus' claim with God's name, which was quite absurd.

Comment: I believe that an interlinear translation provides a word-for-word rendering of the original text. In the case of the 1510 Strong, it should be "εἰμί" rather than "ἐσμεν." According to the NKJV Greek English Interlinear New Testament, when the literal English translation doesn't flow smoothly, they underline the challenging part and provide an idiomatic English translation to make it easier to read.

You may also understand that "εἰμί" is used in several verses like in John 6:35 “I am the bread of life." John 14:6, “I am the way and the truth and the life." I am trying to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the OP has cropped the important part of the image from Bible Hub - the complete image for John 10:30 is reproduced below.  Notice that the verb ἐσμεν (the last word in the line) is the plural form of the verb εἰμί - the latter being the lexical form.

[image]

Note the series of letters below this verb which are "V-PIA-1P" which means, "Verb - Present Active indicative, 1st person plural".  This is exactly equivalent to the English "are" as the above image correctly shows.

The lexical form εἰμί (Strongs 1510) is always the first person singular present indicative active.  The plural form is ἐσμεν = "are".

Comment: The label "V-PIA-1P" is linked to "ἐσμεν" with Strong's number 2070, rather than "εἰμί," which is associated with Strong's number 1510.

When examining the Interlinear text, it's worth noting that the Strong's number used for "ἐσμεν" is actually 1510, not 2070. This creates confusion.